# How to Uninstall UBUNTU without bootable cd

Tags: uninstall

I have installed ubuntu using a bootable cd, is there any way to uninstall ubuntu without cd. Also, I am not getting an option for ubuntu in Add/Remove Programmes

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot from your windows CD/dvd and fix your MBR to point directly to windows instead of to the GRUB bootloader.

Next you have to boot in to windows, and in disk management reclaim your ubuntu partition.

An in depth explanation can be found here:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/